# Update a dataframe's column to a letter's alphabetical position

Tags: r

Attempting to update an alpha character column to respective alphanumeric characters: meaning update "A" to "1".

passing this in the console updates the sdt dataframe for column 5

```
x <- 5
y <- "K"
z <- "1000"
sdt[[x]] <- ifelse(sdt[[x]] == y, z, sdt[[x]])
```

thought to scale it by building this function:

```
texp <- function (x, y, z) {

    x <- as.integer(x)
    y <- as.character(y)
    y <- as.character(z)   
    sdt[[x]] <- ifelse(sdt[[x]] == y, z, sdt[[x]] )          
}
```

then passing this to the console:

```
texp(5, "A", "1")
```

no updates were made. Attempted a variety of variants, none worked (meaning no updates made).

What am I missing?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Add `sdt` before the closing } and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

```
# Update column
sdt[[5]] <- match(tolower(sdt[[5]]), letters)

# transform to numeric
sdt[[5]] <- as.numeric(sdt[[5]])
```

Notes about your code:

1. Inside a function, if you want to modify an existing object, you
   need to use `<<-` instead of `<-` (although this should be used with
   caution).
2. As docendo pointed out, you'd generally want a function to return
   something instead of modifying existing objects. So for instance you
   could have `return(ifelse([your args]))`, and then use your function for
   assigning new values.